# Python - How to make Tkinter window shows in the screen where terminal is currently in?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script mainly running on MacOS terminal. At certain point it will shows a Tkinter window for user to select something. My problem is that If I put the terminal window in a secondary screen (external monitor) and run the script, the Tkinter window always shows up in the primary screen (builtin monitor).

Is there a way to force the Tkinter window shows in the screen where the terminal is in?